# Rename objects in rows and keep track of changed name in R

Tags: r

I have data frame in which one column has name of companies in the row entries. But these are huge and cause inconvenience. So, I would like to rename them but the important part here is I want to keep track that which company has been assigned which new name. As name of companies are character so, I would to give to them numeric names. The reason behind keep tracking which company has been what name is that I have several dataframe and when I have to pull out data for the respective company.
I provide as example

```
df1

    Month   variable
    Jan-05  A
    Feb-05  B
    Mar-05  C
    Apr-05  D
    May-05  E
```

Recode or change the names of the companies

```
df2
Month   variable
Jan-05  1
Feb-05  2
Mar-05  3
Apr-05  4
May-05  5
```

But my dataset has thousand of companies,so, If in df3 which still has the companies names in A,B and C and I want to put out data for company 1 and it will pull out the data for company A.
Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your company name character vector to factor and then change levels of factor as you desire. And document these changes in a separate data frame.

Such as:

```
df <- data.frame(Month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"),
                 variable = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C"))
df$variable <- factor(df$variable)

reference <- data.frame(name = levels(df$variable))
reference$number_code <- c(1,2,3)

levels(df$variable) <- reference$number_code

> df
  Month variable
1   Jan        1
2   Feb        2
3   Mar        3
4   Apr        1
5   May        3
> reference
  name number_code
1    A           1
2    B           2
3    C           3
```